# Page Layout html page field filter outside of web part zone

Tags: 2013, web-part, page-layout, filter, html

I have a page layout with some web parts outside of a webpart zone so that they are added to already created pages which use the page layout.

I want to add a page field filter to the page as well and connect it to the web parts.

I got the filter to add to a page inside of a web part zone, and the connections added outside of the web part zone. However, since the filter is inside of the web part zone, it isn't added to pages I have already created using the layout.

**QUESTION:** How do I add a page field filter to a page layout outside of a web part zone? Is it even possible?

My HTML Snippets for the filter and connections:

```
<!--MS:<WpNs0:PageContextFilterWebPart
    ID="ClientNameFilterId"
    runat="server" PageFieldGuid="031c6c97-22db-4e30-8ebb-ad652b0c8263" FilterName="ClientNameFilterName"
    Title="ClientNameFilterTitle" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" SendEmptyWhenNoValues="True"
    Description="Filter web parts based on the Client Name" IsIncluded="True"
    FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="False" AllowMinimize="True"
    AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif"
    TitleIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default"
    PartImageSmall="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this web part."
    ImportErrorMessage="Cannot import this web part." PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif"
    IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True">-->
<!--ME:</WpNs0:PageContextFilterWebPart>-->

<!--SPM:<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" ID="__ProxyWebPartManagerForConnections__">-->
<!--SPM:    <SPWebPartConnections>-->
<!--SPM:        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="XsltListViewWebPartContacts" ID="ContactClientConnection" ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="ClientNameFilterId">-->
<!--SPM:            <WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer ConsumerFieldNames="Client" ProviderFieldNames="ClientNameFilterName">-->
<!--SPM:            </WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer>-->
<!--SPM:        </WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection>-->
<!--SPM:        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="XsltListViewWebPartProjects" ID="ProjectsClientConnection" ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="ClientNameFilterId">-->
<!--SPM:            <WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer ConsumerFieldNames="Client" ProviderFieldNames="ClientNameFilterName">-->
<!--SPM:            </WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer>-->
<!--SPM:        </WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection>-->
<!--SPM:        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="XsltListViewWebPartClientDocuments" ID="DocumentsClientsConnection" ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="ClientNameFilterId">-->
<!--SPM:            <WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer ConsumerFieldNames="Client" ProviderFieldNames="ClientNameFilterName">-->
<!--SPM:            </WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer>-->
<!--SPM:        </WebPartPages:SPWebPartConnection>-->
<!--SPM:    </SPWebPartConnections>-->
<!--SPM:</WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>-->
```

This is the error I get when I preview the layout or create a new page when the filter snippet is not in a webpart zone snippet:
[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: It is not very clear what you need. In a page layout it is up to you to decide where you put your snippets, and basically it is on the page itself.

Comment: If I put my filter snippet inside of a webpart zone snippet, the page layout works fine. If I don't put my filter snippet inside of a webpart zone snippet, the page layout doesn't work. I can upload it, and it translates into aspx without any errors. However, when I preview the page layout or try to create a page from the layout, I get the error message that I added to my post. I want to put the filter snippet outside of a webpart zone so that any changes I make to the page layout will be reflected in any already created pages which use the layout.

Comment: I have tried and had no troubles to put just in the page. Probably you have to check the content type you are using. Anyway a filter snippet not related to a webpart makes no sense since you cannot set a connection later.

Comment: @Marpio I am connecting the snippet to other webparts on the page which are not in a webpart zone and I have not shown in this question. I can show them if you want me to. Can you post your html which worked?

Comment: Can you get the log details (from file system) for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add a jquery script that will move the existing webpart's div element to the desired location.

This should looks like:

```
$("#source").appendTo("#destination");
```

You can add the script in a Content Webpart or script webpart

Answer (score 0):

djmsmith just add your filter code snippet into Contain placeholder main in the master page and then try to deploy the custom web part zones.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like a discrepancy between configurations of your webpart inside the wpzone vs outside of it.  Maybe take a look at the WP in the wpzone (use SP Designer) and compare your properties to the WP outside the wpzone?